# Add parametr to query string in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How can I add parametr to link in MVC? When I use this (in controller) below code

```
Model model = GetModel();
string lang = "pl";
string viewName = "MyPage";
return View(viewName + "?lang=" + lang, model);
```

I get error
The view '*MyPage?lang=pl*' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ...

Comment: Whats do you intend to do with this query string parameter? Query string parameters in MVC get parsed against the relevant controllers, if you looking at passing an additional parameter for use in the page you should look into using the ViewBag

Comment: I want to have oportunity to send this url to other people

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you retun `View` result ASP.NET MVC simply renders this view for you. It has nothing to url. Url is entered by the user into browser to call your MVC action. If you whant to change the url you should user `RedirectToAction` result. E.g:

```
return RedirectToAction("MyPage", new {lang = "pl"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ViewData or an advanced ViweModel class to pass data to the view.

```
Model model = GetModel();
ViewData["lang"] = "pl";
return View("MyPage", model);
```

Of course if you referring to the query string in your view (which is bad) fix it to reference to the ViewData.